# How to install Apache Cordova extension in Visual studio 2015 Enterprise?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015

I have recently installed VS 2015 Enterprise and while installing I didn't get any place where VS asked to select anything related to Apache Cordova extension. When I am trying to create a Apache Cordova Project it says that Tools for Apache Cordova are not installed and click ok to install. When I am clicking on "OK" Button after some time I am getting Setup page window. In short it's not installing the extension. How Can I install Apache Cordova if I have already installed VS 2015 Enterprise and haven't selected it while installing VS?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have Visual Studio 2015 installed already, go to control panel open add/remove software, select Visual Studio 2015 and choose modify, you will see an option for **Cross Platform Mobile Development**, select this and update.

[image: Cross Platform Mobile Development]

If you don't have VS2015 installed already you can follow this guide to install Cordova tools for VS

http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/install-vs-tools-apache-cordova/

Comment: is there any offline installer available for it !! @BhavO